# MySQL TimeDiff to exclude weekends

Tags: mysql

I've been using TimeDiff on a MySQL table to get the difference between 2 fields, both in the DateTime format. Here's the query I'm using, which also limits the durations down to this year alone.

```
SELECT username, CONCAT(
FLOOR(SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) / 24)), ' days ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)), 24), ' hours ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)), ' minutes')
AS duration
FROM table
WHERE start_time > CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()) -1, '-12-31')
GROUP BY username
```

The problem I'm having is that I've been having difficulty in trying to work out how to exclude weekends from the result. Can anyone help please?

Comment: There are some great ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222563/mysql-calculate-the-difference-between-date-times-only-during-m-f-work-week).

Comment: Define "exclude weekends from the result". Do you mean to subtract the weekend hours from the `duration`, or exclude records that start, end, or contain a weekend?

Comment: He actually wants to subtract the weekend hours from the duration.

Answer (score 4):

For the purpose of example we use static `@start` and `@end` dates, but in practice you can replace them with your column names and all of these values will be recalculated per-row.

```
SET @start  = '2012-09-30';
SET @end    = '2012-11-03';

SELECT
    @raw_days   := DATEDIFF(@end, @start)+1 'raw_days',
    @full_weeks := FLOOR(@raw_days / 7) 'full_weeks',
    @odd_days   := @raw_days - @full_weeks * 7 'odd_days',
    @wday_start := DAYOFWEEK(@start) 'wday_start',
    @wday_end   := DAYOFWEEK(@end) 'wday_end',
    @weekend_intrusion  := @wday_start + @odd_days 'weekend_intrusion',
    @extra_weekends     :=
        IF(@wday_start = 1, IF(@odd_days = 0, 0, 1),
            IF(@weekend_intrusion > 7, 2,
                IF(@weekend_intrusion > 6, 1, 0)
            )
        ) 'extra_weekends',
    @total_weekends     := @full_weeks * 2 + @extra_weekends 'total_weekends',
    @total_workdays     := @raw_days - @total_weekends 'total_workdays'
```

The `IF` statements boil down to:

If the week starts on a Sunday, and there are no 'odd' days, then there are no extra weekend days. If there *are* odd days, then there can only be 1 weekend day since it can't possibly stretch to Saturday since that would be a 'full' week.

Otherwise, we see if the remaining portion of a week extends past Sunday. If so, add 2 weekend days. Else if the portion goes to Saturday, add 1 weekend day. Else 0.

Output:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| raw_days | full_weeks | odd_days | wday_start | wday_end | weekend_intrusion | extra_weekends | total_weekends | total_workdays |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       34 |          4 |        6 |          1 |        6 |                 7 |              1 |              9 |             25 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+----------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

heres a bulk solution that i just developed using my date dimension table it allows start and end to be during a weekend.

```
Select
    f.id, f.dtStart, f.dtEnd,
    sec_to_time(
    sum(
        case 
            -- don't count weekends
            when day_in_week in (6,7) 
                then 0
            -- start and end on same day
            when date(f.dtStart) = date(f.dtEnd) 
                then UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f.dtEnd) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(f.dtStart)
            -- start period
            when date(f.dtStart) = dt.date_value
                then 24*60*60 - time_to_sec(time(f.dtStart))
            -- end period
            when date(f.dtEnd) = dt.date_value
                then time_to_sec(time(f.dtEnd))
            -- middle days
            else 24*60*60
        end
    )
    ) INT_timediff,
From fact f
join dim_date dt
    on dt.date_value between date(f.dtStart) and date(f.dtEnd)
group by f.id, f.dtStart, f.dtEnd
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
username, 
CONCAT(
    FLOOR(
        SUM(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) - 86400 * (
                (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) / 7) * 2) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) > 4, WEEKDAY(end_time) - 4, 0) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) < WEEKDAY(start_time), 2, 0)
            )
        ) / 86400
    ),
    ' days ',
    TIME_FORMAT(
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        SUM(
            UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) - 86400 * (
                (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) / 7) * 2) +
                    IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) > 4, WEEKDAY(end_time) - 4, 0) + 
                    IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) < WEEKDAY(start_time), 2, 0)
            )
        ) % 86400
    ),
    '%H hours %i minutes'
    )
) AS duration
FROM table
WHERE start_time > CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()) -1, '-12-31')
GROUP BY username;
```

but it assumes that `start_time` and `end_time` never falls during a weekend.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/3587 for a working example.

If you don't care about an extra column, this query can be simplified as:

```
SELECT
@diff := SUM(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(end_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time) - 86400 * (
        (FLOOR(DATEDIFF(end_time, start_time) / 7) * 2) +
            IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) > 4, WEEKDAY(end_time) - 4, 0) + 
            IF(WEEKDAY(end_time) < WEEKDAY(start_time), 2, 0)
    )
) AS duration_seconds,
CONCAT(
    FLOOR(@diff / 86400),
    ' days ',
    TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(@diff % 86400), '%H hours %i minutes')
) AS duration
FROM table
WHERE start_time > CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()) -1, '-12-31')
GROUP BY username;
```